# "Later, Magellan became involved in an insular conflict in the Philippines" What does "Insular" mean here?

Tags: meaning, idioms, interjections

> "Later, Magellan became involved in an insular conflict in the Philippines"

What does "Insular" mean here?

As far as Cambridge Dictionary is concerned,

[Insular](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/insular) means:

> - "interested only in your own country or group and not willing to accept different or foreign ideas".

I can not understand that sentence with the help of this meaning.  Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 2):

One meaning of [Insular](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/insular) according to TFD is:

> Circumscribed and detached in outlook and experience; narrow or provincial

This is similar to what you found in the Cambridge Dictionary:

> interested only in your own country or group and not willing to accept different or foreign ideas

Note that it has another meaning too:

> Of, relating to, or constituting an island.

In your sentence:

> Magellan became involved in an insular conflict in the Philippines

it means that Magellan became involved in a conflict *amongst the islands* which make up the Philippines.

The [Philippines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philippines) is an archipelagic country consisting of about 7,641 islands in the Western Pacific ocean

Comment: So would a localised conflict about an island be an "insular insular conflict" ?

Comment: @mgb see Chagos dispute between The UK and Mauritius - an insular insular insular dispute :D http://www.businessinsider.com/18-island-disputes-2015-4